# How to lock the screen with autoIT win8.1

Tags: windows, autoit

I try to make a program, which locks the screen.
I tried `Send("#l")`, and it does not work, although `#f` and `#r` works perfectly.

`Send("{LWINDOWN}{l}{LWINUP}")` does not work either.

I am using autoIT 3, 32 bit version, on a 64 bit PC. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I solved the problem using    MouseMove() and    MouseClick()

Answer (score 2):

In an actually elegant way, use the predefined WinAPI.au3 function

```
_WinAPI_LockWorkStation
```

See the offline helpfile for this UDF, and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875(v=vs.85).aspx) for it's effect on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it more elegantly with this:

> Run(@COMSPEC & ' /c ' & 'rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation',"",@SW_HIDE)

Comment: The procedure for using Windows API functions is: 1. Look at the WinAPI.au3 help articles to see if it is pre-defined. 2. When it is not, use `DllCall` to invoke the function from the respective system library. `Run` should be the last option ever, because there is no built-in way of error handling. With UDFs, you may use `@error` or `_WinAPI_GetLastError`